# ios upload image with multiple parameters to server

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, https, http-headers

I am trying to upload an image with some other variables but I failed. Please tell me where I am doing mistake. I have provided some variables at the top of the code e.g. type , copies and sizing etc . If I post these values to the server without the image parameter It posted successfully But when I try to upload the image with it then it failed. Please watch the code and tell me where I am doing wrong.

```
`UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"java_url.jpg"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,90);
NSString *md5Hash = [self md5:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data]];
NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@",@"type", @"8x12" ]];

[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@",@"copies", @"2"]];
[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@",@"sizing", kSizingOptionShrinkToFit]];
[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%d",@"priceToUser", 5]];
  [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", @"md5Hash",md5Hash]];

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://sandbox.pwinty.com/v2/Orders/%@/Photos",OrderId];
NSString *filename = @"facebook_contest_image.png";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"72c56256-95a4-44e8-be31-b7b3a0b094b7" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Pwinty-MerchantId"];
[request addValue:@"3a1f6f29-d6e1-4f3f-9891-27e5d4f90009" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Pwinty-REST-API-Key"];
[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", @"file",postbody]];
NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSLog(@"%@",postData);
[request setHTTPBody:postbody];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString  *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", returnString);`
```

Comment: do you have to upload image and extra parameters on same time ?

Comment: Yes same time with single post request

Answer (score 0):

I normally use AFNetworking its best library out there for any server requests try this code bellow,
it required AFNetworking

```
- (void)upload {

    // !!! only JPG, PNG not covered! Have to cover PNG as well
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%c%c.jpg", (long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970], arc4random_uniform(26) + 'a', arc4random_uniform(26) + 'a'];
    // NSLog(@"FileName == %@", fileName);

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"lat": @"8.444444",
                                 @"lng": @"50.44444",
                                 @"location": @"New York",
                                 @"type": @"2",
                                 @"claim": @"NYC",
                                 @"flag": @"0"};
     // BASIC AUTH (if you need):
    manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"foo" password:@"bar"];
    // BASIC AUTH END

    NSString *URLString = @"http://192.168.1.157/tapp/laravel/public/foobar/upload";

    /// !!! only jpg, have to cover png as well
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image, 0.5); // image size ca. 50 KB
    [manager POST:URLString parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:fileName mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure %@, %@", error, operation.responseString);
    }];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I have done exactly same but was unsuccessful. If I post data without image the rest of the variables posted successfully, But while uploading image it generates the following error Failure Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo=0x8e5de00 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://sandbox.pwinty.com/v2/Orders/70263/Photos, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey= NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500)}, {"errorMessage":"Unknown server error"}